# Detecting timeouts in a stream of events

Tags: python, performance, interview-questions

I'm trying to come up with a solution to this [interview question](https://leetcode.com/discuss/interview-question/924141/google-phone-screen-new-grad):

> You have a stream of RPC requests coming into a server which is being
> logged. Each log entry is of the form [id, timestamp,
> type ('Start' or 'End')]. Given a sequence of log entries and a timeout value, you need to figure
> out at the earliest possible time if an RPC call has timed out (e.g.
> print a message as soon as you detect such situation).
>
> ```
> Example:
> Timeout = 3
> id - time - type
> 0 - 0 - Start
> 1 - 1 - Start
> 0 - 2 - End
> 2 - 6 - Start  # figured out id 1 had timed out at time 6
> 1 - 7 - End
> ```

I believe that my solution is `O(NlogN)`, is there any way to improve it?

```
from sortedcontainers import SortedList


def process_log(log: list[list], timeout=3):
    rpc_ids = {}
    rpcs = SortedList()

    for rpc_id, timestamp, action in log:
        if action == 'Start':
            rpcs.add([timestamp, rpc_id])
            rpc_ids[rpc_id] = timestamp
        else:
            if rpc_id in rpc_ids:
                entry = [rpc_ids[rpc_id], rpc_id]
                if timestamp - rpc_ids[rpc_id] > timeout:
                    report_rpc(rpc_id, rpc_ids[rpc_id], timestamp)
                del rpc_ids[rpc_id]
                rpcs.remove(entry)

        idx = rpcs.bisect_left([timestamp-timeout, float('inf')])

        if idx > 0:
            for i in range(idx):
                start_time, rpc_id = rpcs[i]
                report_rpc(rpc_id, start_time, timestamp)
                del rpc_ids[rpc_id]
            del rpcs[:idx]


def report_rpc(rpc_id, start_time, timestamp):
    print(f'RPC #{rpc_id} started at {start_time} has timed out (@{timestamp})')


process_log([  # RPC #1 times out at timestamp 6
    [0, 0, 'Start'],
    [1, 1, 'Start'],
    [0, 2, 'End'],
    [2, 6, 'Start'],
    [1, 7, 'End'],
])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a `O(n)` solution using just a dictionary:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass(frozen=True, slots=True)
class LogEntry:
    rpc_id: int
    timestamp: int
    action: str


class LogProcessor:
    def __init__(self, timeout: int):
        self.entries: dict[int, LogEntry] = {}
        self.timeout = timeout

    def process_log_entry(self, entry: LogEntry) -> list[LogEntry]:
        if entry.action == 'Start':
            self.entries[entry.rpc_id] = entry
        elif entry.rpc_id in self.entries and entry.timestamp - self.entries[entry.rpc_id].timestamp <= self.timeout:
            del self.entries[entry.rpc_id]

        timed_out = []

        for e in self.entries.values():
            if entry.timestamp - e.timestamp <= self.timeout:
                break
            timed_out.append(e)

        for e in timed_out:
            del self.entries[e.rpc_id]

        return timed_out


log_processor = LogProcessor(timeout=3)

assert log_processor.process_log_entry(LogEntry(1, 0, 'Start')) == []
assert log_processor.process_log_entry(LogEntry(2, 1, 'Start')) == []
assert log_processor.process_log_entry(LogEntry(1, 2, 'End')) == []
assert log_processor.process_log_entry(LogEntry(3, 6, 'Start')) == [LogEntry(2, 1, 'Start')]
```

As Python dictionaries are insertion ordered, we can check for timed out entries on each call to `process_log_entry()` by iterating once from the beginning of the dictionary. Since we remove timed out entries immediately after the iteration, the total time complexity will still be `O(n)`.

P.S. The code has also been refactored to use a dataclass for log entry and a class for log processor, which should be more readable/maintainable.